# Remove hidden characters from an excel.csv file

Tags: excel, sed, command-line-interface

I have a large excel file containing a list of numbers (numbers.csv)

```
1234
1235
1236
1237
```

However when I use

```
cat numbers.csv
```

it returns

```
1234,,
1235,,
1236,,
1237,,
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, but I think sed might be the right approach? relatively new to this, so trying to figure it out.

I would like generate a new file (numbers2.csv) to just contain the numbers and no ,, or other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
sed 's/,//g' numbers.csv 
1234
1235
1236
1237
```

If you like to edit the original file.

```
sed -i 's/,//g' numbers.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Jotne 

I used 

sed 's/,//g' numbers.csv  > output.txt

Which created a new output.txt file without and ,,